# How to used Cons operator?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, ml

Basically the function will take one parameter as a character, number and check whether it is inside the List or not ?

```
let rec (member: a -> List a -> Bool) x = 
 | [] -> False
 | Cons y ys -> if x == y then True else member x ys 
;;
```

I got the solution but it seems too vague.

Could anyone show me how to use Cons operator in this particular case ?

Thanks

Comment: You should tag your question with the programming language (Haskell?)

Answer (score 4):

In Ocaml, the cons operator is `::`. But it is not the only problem of your piece of code.

Here your function takes only one argument (`x`) but you use it with two (`member x ys`), you wanted to do `let rec member x l = match l with` or `let rec member x = function` which is equivalent.

In OCaml you don't have to give the type of your values, but if you do, this is not the rigth syntax. OCaml types are not capitalized, type parameters start with `'`
 and are placed before the type they parameterize, then the type of your function is `'a -> 'a list -> bool`. Moreover, for a function you have to give the type of the parameters and the return type separately (`let rec member (x : 'a) (l : 'a list) : bool =`).

The operator for equality is `=` and not `==`.

Even if it is correct, don't use `if then else` to return a boolean, logical operators `||` and `&&` should be used instead.

Corrected code:

```
let rec member x = function
| [] -> false
| y :: ys -> x = y || member x ys
```

Comment: it is also possible to put the whole function type in one go before its "prototype" (`let member : 'a -> 'a list -> bool = fun x l -> ...`). Either way OP was incorrect there, as you rightly pointed out.